# How do C programmers work with the MSDN API examples which are in C++?

Tags: c

I am getting into GUI programming with C for fun. I presume that GTK isn't complete enough to deal with potentially all the win32 calls that can be made/hooked.  I've gone through the examples from the few sites I could find that give tutorials on the common API calls (with C focus), but when I look up the MSDN on API calls that aren't covered, I see that the explanations/examples are in C++.  What do C programmers do at this point?

Comment: The vast majority of the winapi sample code in MSDN is actually in C.  Naturally so, the winapi is a C api.  I suspect you are finding MFC topics, a C++ class library.  Not sure why we have to guess at what MSDN articles you found.

Comment: @Hans Passant http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183362%28v=vs.85%29.aspx The painting and drawing functions are all C++ examples. There is no signposting to say what is MFc that I can see.

Comment: There's no code on that page.  The "Drawing in the Client Area" example code it links to is pure C code.

Comment: @ hans Passant it clearly says "syntax C++", what??

Comment: The parent page of this library is here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee663266.aspx - which says: "Learn the basics of building great desktop apps in C++." ....

Comment: On the MSDN pages, all C code examples will be labeled as C++.

Comment: @ scaryrawr so are you saying that all of the API code is C? No C++? Why would they advertise the entire API guide as C++ then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The examples aren't really there for people to directly copy&paste them. They're just examples. Even if the example is in C++, it gets the point across both for C as well as C++ because both languages share a lot of syntax. And since WINAPI is a C API, even when used with C++, the example code is going to be quite compatible with C; there aren't any classes or templates or anything else C++-related in WINAPI.

As for the reason MS is doing this, it's because Visual Studio is a C++ environment. Yes, there's a C89 compiler included, but it's just for backwards compatibility.

Comment: I suppose I understand :/.. but some of them have just an example with no clear usage instructions which would be a nightmare if you don't have a C++ background I think.

Comment: @user1166981 Personally I've never actually found an example on MSDN that doesn't compile as-is with plain C. You should be OK.